# Content value cannot access value.put();

Tags: java, android, xml

I was tying to implement Sqlite, to save data in my android application. 
(by  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html#WriteDbRow ) 
However, I couldnt simply create a new map of values by using Content

```
 public static final class FeedReaderContract {
        // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
        // make the constructor private.
        private FeedReaderContract() {}

        /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
        public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
            public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
            public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
        }


        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                        FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT," +
                        FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + " TEXT)";

        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    }
    public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

        public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
            // to simply to discard the data and start over
            db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }


        FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getBaseContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db= mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
        values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, subtitle);



    }
```

Android studio autocorrect first one to  values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title); 
which also results in error : Unknown class;
second one says : Unknown Symbol. 
Btw, If you know any good and simple source from which I can learn using sqlite in android studio, I would be thankful if you share it

Comment: Looks like the lines with values.put(...) are not part of any method.Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method so it would look like this:

```
public boolean insert(String title,String subtitle)
{
    FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getBaseContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db= mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, subtitle);
    long ins = db.insert("entry",null,values);
    if(ins == -1) return false;
    else return true;

}
```

Basically this method will return a boolean value depending on wether the insert was successful or not.

Oh and you have a mistake in the onCreate() method....
Replace this code:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    }
```

With this:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
   }
```